# VBA Code to move cells if they contain a specific indent

Tags: excel, vba, indentation, data-cleaning

I am looking to write a code in VBA to sort my data into adjacent columns based on their level of indentation. I managed to write a code that works properly based on the number of spaces beginning in the cell, however I cannot seem to find a way to move them based on indentation. Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
Sub Movecellindent()
Dim row As Long

For row = 3 To 3000
    'cells that begin with 15 spaces are moved to column D
    If Range("A" & row).Value Like "               *" Then
        Range("D" & row).Value = Range("A" & row).Value
        Range("A" & row).Value = ""
    End If
Next
For row = 3 To 3000
    'cells beginning with 12 spaces are moved to column C
    If Range("A" & row).Value Like "            *" Then
        Range("C" & row).Value = Range("A" & row).Value
        Range("A" & row).Value = ""
    End If
Next
For row = 3 To 3000
    'cells beginning with 10 spaces are moved to column B
    If Range("A" & row).Value Like "          *" Then
        Range("B" & row).Value = Range("A" & row).Value
        Range("A" & row).Value = ""
    End If
Next
```

Instead of the code written above, I want the code to perform the same action but with 3, 2 and 1 indents, respectively.

Thank you!

Comment: Use the `IndentLevel` property, if they are true indentations.

Comment: In order to count the number of spaces in front of a string, you can calculate the length which is subtracted by the `LTrim()` worksheet function: `Len(S) - Len(LTrim(S))`: if `S` equals `   AA`, then `Len(S)`=5, `LTrim(S)`="AA", `Len(LTrim(S))`=2, so the difference is 3.

Comment: see  https://professor-excel.com/how-to-return-the-indentation-of-a-cell-in-excel/